# Conditionals inside table

Tags: macros, conditionals, tabularx, ifthenelse

i have several documents that display tables.
Certain rows are shared among documents, so they are in a separate file.
These rows should contain if statements to print different things depending on the main file that calls them (each main file sets a command to a certain value).
Unfortunately, the argument that is dictating this branching is itself argument of another branching in the command used to display rows.

The point is: this argument is often null `{}`, so i don't want anything displayed there, and when it's not null i want the argument (so far so good). Then, when i have the argument, sometimes, based on the file where i am, i want to print two different things.

Here's the MWE that does this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\name}[0]{one}
\newcommand{\myrow}[3]{#1 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{;#3} & #2 \\\hline}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{| X | X | }
    \hline
    \myrow{A}{B}{C}      %this one prints  | A;C | B |
    \myrow{A}{B}{}       %this one prints  | A | B |
    \input{non-functioning-row}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Intuitively there'll be another file like this one with a single difference, it sets the \name to "two".

While file "non-funtioning-row" file contains

```
\myrow{A}{B}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\name}{one}}{one}{two}}
```

Some time ago i played with another if-then-else package that should be better than this one but failed to achieve what i want.

Comment: the problem here is unrelated to tables, it is simply that nested `\iftenelse` `\equal` tests do not work the way you are expecting. `\ifthenelse{...}{A}{B}` does not _expand_ to `A` (even if it results in the A branch being taken) so it will never test `\equal` to `A` in an outer `\ifthenelse` test.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `\ifx` etc. and some test with `\empty` and definition of the test macros such that it is easier change the conditions, say `\fooone` and `\footwo` instead of literal `one` and `two`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\fooone}{one}
\newcommand{\footwo}{two}
\newcommand{\name}{one}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myrow}[3]{\def\foobar{#3}#1 \ifx\foobar\empty\else;#3\fi & #2\\ \hline}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{| X | X | }
    \hline
    \myrow{A}{B}{C}      %this one prints  | A;C | B |
    \myrow{A}{B}{}       %this one prints  | A | B 
    \input{notworking}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Whereas `notworking.tex` contains

```
\myrow{A}{B}{\ifx\name\fooone\relax\fooone\else \footwo\fi}
```

[image]

Comment: there must be something wrong, as this thing prints the ";" in the second row as well, but that should only be printed when C is not {}

Comment: @Squera: Replace `\@empty` by `\empty`, please